# How do triggers affect last_insert_id()?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am unable to test this right now, however I'm curious about the answer.

If I have a trigger on table A that writes a new record to table B, will `LAST_INSERT_ID()` tell me the updated `ID` for A or B?  I'm curious about both MySQL and PHP, but my understanding is that PHP simply calls MySQL's implementation.

How do I get the last inserted ID for B if it normally returns A, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 4):

From [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> The effect of a stored routine or trigger upon the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() that is seen by following statements depends on the kind of routine:
>     ....
>     For stored functions and triggers that change the value, the value is restored when the function or trigger ends, so following statements do not see a changed value. (Before MySQL 5.0.12, the value is not restored and following statements do see a changed value.)

Thus whatever happens inside the trigger[s] on A does not affect value returned by  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` executed outside of trigger's body. Withing the trigger body `LAST_INSERT_ID` will reflect inserts you made to another table. To get last id for B you need to store the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` somewhere(new table, or a new column in A), for instance,

```
delimiter /

CREATE trigger biA before insert on A
for each row

begin
 insert into B(name) values('aaa');
 set new.b_id := (select last_insert_id());
end;
/
```